# how to resolve if condition inside foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

```
<?php
$login_info = array('batman'=>'404','superman'=>'502');
$form_usr = "$_POST[usr]";
$form_pass = "$_POST[pass]";
$form_submit = "$_POST[submit]";

if ( isset($form_submit) ) {
    foreach ( $login_info as $user => $pass ) {
        if ($form_usr == $user && $form_pass == $pass) {
            echo "Successfully logged in !"; 
        }
        else {
            echo "bad username or password !";
        }
    }
}?>
```

I'm getting `bad username or password !bad username or password !` and `Successfully logged in !bad username or password !` How can i solve this? I'm trying to show up `Successfully logged in !` when condition is true else `bad username or password !`

Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmTiG.png

Comment: You need to debug this. `var_dump($login_info);`. Not sure about your variables btw. For example: `$form_usr = "$_POST[usr]";` would be for me: `$form_usr = $_POST['usr'];` Will this work?

Comment: first of all do that by query, second you missed `$_POST['usr']` `''`

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've changed "$_POST[usr]" to $_POST['usr']  but still same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the loop altogether, instead just **check your variables** exist in the array.

```
<?php
$login_info = array('batman'=>'404','superman'=>'502');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $user = isset($_POST['usr']) ? $_POST['usr'] : null;
    $pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : null;

    if (isset($login_info[$user]) && $login_info[$user] == $pass) {
        echo "Successfully logged in !"; 
    } else {
        echo "bad username or password !";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on a theme perhaps but you could try like this, again not using a loop.

```
<?php

    $message='bad username or password!';

    $login_info = array('batman'=>'404','superman'=>'502');
    $form_usr = isset( $_POST['usr'] ) ? $_POST['usr'] : false;
    $form_pass = isset( $_POST['pass'] ) ? $_POST['pass'] : false;
    $form_submit = isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ? $_POST['submit'] : false;

    if ( $form_submit && $form_usr && $form_pass ) {
        if( array_key_exists( $form_usr, $login_info ) && $login_info[ $form_usr ]==$form_pass ){
            $message="Successfully logged in !";
        }
        echo $message;
    }

?>
```