# i need help to login with array based logins with php

Tags: php

so heres a code that i use on my little website just for myself but i need help
with adding users in an array since i dont wanna use mysql heres an example of what i mean...

```
ex) $user = array("lol", "lol1", "lol2", "lol3");
ex2) $pass = array("lol", "lol1", "lol2", "lol3");

<?php

// Start the session
session_start();

// Defines username and password. Retrieve however you like,
$user = "lol";
$pass = "lol";

// Error message
$error = "";

// Checks to see if the user is already logged in. If so, refirect to correct page.
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true) {
    $error = "success";
    header('Location: success.php');
} 

// Checks to see if the username and password have been entered.
// If so and are equal to the username and password defined above, log them in.
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if ($_POST['username'] == $user && $_POST['password'] == $pass) {
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
        header('Location: success.php');
    } else {
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false;
        $error = "Invalid username and password!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788516/how-to-resolve-if-condition-inside-foreach-loop/47788624#47788624

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check if the posted username is in the $user array or not. if it is available, get the key from $user array and compare password in $pass array with the key.

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    // get key of posted username from $user array, will be false if not available  
    if(($key = array_search($_POST['username'], $username)) !== NULL){ 
        // now check the password
      if($_POST['password'] == $password[$key]){
         $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
         header('Location: success.php'); 
      }
    }
}

$username = array('user1','user2');
$password = array ('pass1','pass2');
```

the combination of *user1 / pass1*  or *user2 / pass2* will allow you login in.

Comment: so how would i make the array of passwords could you re write the script as an example?

Comment: I same way like you did in your question.

Comment: i couldnt get it to work but this is my full code maybe you can see the issue https://pastebin.com/9ZzcMf8R

Comment: nope still doesnt work it just does nothing tries going back to login page

Comment: here i loaded your script into my server and still wont work http://connectionstress.com/login.php

Comment: heres the code for the page that its suppose to redirect to maybe theres a problem with it https://pastebin.com/N0HWd1be

Comment: since form action is empty, you need to add php code in same page (login.php).

Comment: i added login.php inside of form action and still same problem https://pastebin.com/ftgT6DNN

Comment: try to debug, add echo and exit in each if condition and check where the exact issue is

Comment: im not really good at php my main language is python im very new to this could you do that to this code (https://pastebin.com/tuEUiEwL) and then ill try it out

Comment: ok so the thing is the code works whenever success.php isnt inside the server maybe try looking at success.php cause the login.php works perfect success.php: https://pastebin.com/kbracwW0